# How to get a sequence of finer and finer granularity: 1, 16, 8, 4, 12, ...?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, breadth-first-search

If there is a test, where a delta needs to be added to a particular value, the delta can be tested in this sequence: 1, 2, 3, ... 15, 16.

But to test with finer and finer granularity, delta can be this sequence: 1, 16, 8, 4, 12, ...  (that is, we try 1, and 16, which are two extreme cases, and then we try 8, which is a middle number, and then 4, which is middle of 1 and 8, and then 12, which is middle of 8 and 16).

How can this sequence be generated elegantly without duplicates?

Right now I have this in Ruby 1.9.3:

```
$deltas = []

def getMidPoint(a, b)
  return if (a - b).abs <= 1

  midPoint = ((a + b) / 2).to_i
  puts "a = #{a}, b = #{b}, midPoint = #{midPoint}"

  $deltas << midPoint
  getMidPoint(a, midPoint)
  getMidPoint(midPoint, b)
end

$deltas << 1
$deltas << 16
getMidPoint(1, 16)

p $deltas
```

but the result is:

```
[1, 16, 8, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 7, 12, 10, 9, 11, 14, 13, 15]
```

I can actually add a "level" to the number (stored as a tuple): so for 8, it is level 2, and for 12, it is also level 2 (the level is the recursion level), and then at the end, I can collect the numbers with level 1, and then level 2, etc, to get the final array, and it should work, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that it will runthrough the entire "left side" before going to the "right side", because the `getMidPoint(a, midPoint)` will cause many recursions before `getMidPoint(midPoint, b)` executes.

One possible solution is to use a queue. Enqueue the calls instead of calling both functions directly and always call the first element in the queue.

So in the first step you would output 8 and have the queue <1,8>, <8,16> and you would call <1,8>, outputing 4. Next you would have <8,16><1,4><4,8> and you would call <8,16> and output 12 and have the queue <1,4><4,8><8,12><12,16> and so on.

I think it is a better approximation to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

if the number of items is not big (in my real case, it can be 16 or at most 300), that is, if time complexity is not an issue, then it actually can be done by stepping with smaller and smaller granularity:

```
starting_value = 1
ending_value = 16
queue = [] << starting_value << ending_value

each_step = ((starting_value + ending_value) / 2).to_i
begin
  starting_value.step(ending_value, each_step) {|i| queue << i if not queue.include? i}
  each_step = (each_step / 2).to_i
end while each_step > 0

p queue
```

and the result is:

```
[1, 16, 9, 5, 13, 3, 7, 11, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

The `queue.include?` can make the algorithm `O(n * n * log n)`, but if a hash table is used to check whether the number is already added, then it can become `O(n log n)` it seems.